# Segmentation Fault in C entering character into array

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault

Im trying to enter in various nucleotide bases into an array but am having problems with my array. It is either returning a segmentation fault after I enter a character or the loop is running 3x before prompting me for another character. Thank you for your help in advance.

**Here is my code**:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<ctype.h>

int main(void)
{
    char strand[20];
    char nucleotide;
    int position=0;

    while(position<20)
    {
        printf("Enter one capital character:\n");
        scanf("%c",nucleotide);
        if(toupper(nucleotide) == 'A')
        {
            printf("You entered an A\n",nucleotide);
            strand[position] = nucleotide; // store the letter in an array
            position = position + 1; // gives the new letter a position in the array
        }
        else if(toupper(nucleotide) == 'G')
        {
            printf("You entered a G\n");
            strand[position] = nucleotide; // store the letter in an array
            position = position + 1; // gives the new letter a position in the array
        }
        else if(toupper(nucleotide) == 'C')
        {
            printf("You entered a C\n");
            strand[position] = nucleotide; // store the letter in an array
            position = position + 1; // gives the new letter a position in the array
        }
        else if(toupper(nucleotide) == 'U')
        {
            printf("You entered a U\n");
            strand[position] = nucleotide; // store the letter in an array
            position = position + 1; // gives the new letter a position in the array
        }
        else
        {
            printf("You have not entered a valid character.\n Please enter a character found in an RNA strand.\n");
        }
        printf("Congratulations, you entered %c\n",nucleotide);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to edit your question to make it more readable. Hit `edit` just under the flags at the bottom of your question. Then select all your code in your question. Hit `{}` at the top of the edit box. And submit edited question. And remove all those blank lines between each code of line, makes it longer than required.

Comment: `scanf(" %c",&nucleotide);`

Comment: Please stop giving him fish by fixing code formatting for him. This is something every SO user needs to learn how to do, so editing the post is not helpful. People do need to bother a bit and at the very least cast a quick glance at their own question before posting it.

Comment: what does the "&" symbol do before "nucleotide"

Comment: @Pjhawkeyes Why wouldn't you look in a book?

Comment: nevermind i am an idiot thanks so much for your help

Comment: Yes, the answer will be in chapter 1 of your beginner's C book...

Comment: i dont have a book for this class.

Comment: @Pjhawkeyes Then you're screwed. Too bad.

Comment: @Pjhawkeyes So find one! "'In the age of information, ignorance is a choice." (c)Donny Miller

Comment: yea this is bioinformatics so i didnt really know i needed a book. i ordered one off amazon but my professor made this due before the book comes

Comment: You don't need a book to find these things out. SO is there for you. Its first goal is to provide a searchable data base for questions and answers. Please search it first before asking a question yourself. There are a lot, really a lot of Q&A related to C and `scanf`.

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is `scanf("%c",nucleotide);` change it with `scanf("%c",&nucleotide);` because scanf accepts pointer as an argument.

Also you don't need to know which char was entered, you may do it like that:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>

int main(void) {
    char strand[20];
    char nucleotide;
    int  position = 0, i;

    while (position < 20) {
        printf("Enter one capital character:\n");
        scanf("%c", &nucleotide);

        if (toupper(nucleotide) == 'A' || toupper(nucleotide) == 'G' || toupper(nucleotide) == 'C' ||
            toupper(nucleotide) == 'U') {
            printf("You entered an %c\n", toupper(nucleotide));
            strand[position] = nucleotide; // store the letter in an array
            ++position;// gives the new letter a position in the array
        } else
            printf("You have not entered a valid character.\n Please enter a character found in an RNA strand.\n");

        printf("Congratulations, you entered %c\n", nucleotide);
    }

    printf("Your sequence is: ");
    for (i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
        printf("%c", strand[i]);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You Have left &-Symbol in the part.... { scanf("%c",nucleotide); }

```
while(position<20)

{

    printf("Enter one capital character:\n");

    scanf("%c",nucleotide);

    if(toupper(nucleotide) == 'A')
```

Many times when it shows Segmentation fault first check for the '&' in scanf()
other reasons are also there you can read that from any good c websites...or the book deapth of C....Segmentation faults are alwayse run time error...it never show error durring compilation....

Answer (score 0):

When I compile your code I get this from the compiler.

> gcc main.c
>   main.c: In function ‘main’:
>   main.c:20:9: warning: format ‘%c’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat]

The compiler is telling you that it is expecting type char* for argument 2. Your 2nd argument is `nucleotide` which you declared of type char.
In this particular case the solution is to add `&` to the left of `nucleotide` since that returns a pointer to nucleotide which is what scanf is expecting as 2nd argument.

But the important lesson here is that **you should read compiler warnings and errors** since quite often they are good enough to know where the problem lies.

Comment: why would you be compiling this C code with a C++ compiler?

Comment: A mistake is the only possible explanation for that. Time to delete my answer.

Comment: Or rather edit  it with the correct messages for a C compiler. Thanks for noticing Jens Gustedt.